# Genexus Integration with Ssas

Tags: genexus

Is it possible in Genexus to consume data from SSAS olap cubes?

Im new to Genexus, and couldn’t find enough information about it, or maybe not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

No, GeneXus does not support SSAS olap cubes